# Utilizar función fill de forma masiva

Tags: php8, laravel-9

Estoy intentando realizar la inserción masiva de registros por medio de una asociación en Laravel, no obstante, al momento de utilizar la función fill del módelo, se queda con los datos del ultimo registro

```
//información validada en el request
$payload = $request->validated();
//modelo al que deben ir asociados los nuevos registros
$branch = $this->branchService->find($payload['branch_id']);
foreach(FlyerTypeEnum::cases() as $flyerType){
    if($request->hasFile($flyerType->value)){
        //directorio donde se almacena la información
        $path = 'flyers/' . $payload['branch_id'] . '/' . $flyerType->value . date('-YmdHis.') . $request->file($flyerType->value)->extension();
        if(Storage::disk('public')->put($path, file_get_contents($request->file($flyerType->value)))){
            //en caso de haberse guardado el archivo de forma exitosa, por medio de el metodo fill del modelo, se prepara para la asociacion
            $flyer = $this->service->fillAttributes(array_merge($payload, [
                'enum' => $flyerType->name,
                'path' => $path
            ]));
            //se guarda el registro por medio de la relación
            $branch->flyers()->save($flyer);
        }
    }
}
```

Sin embargo, al momento de realizar la inserción a la base de datos, unicamente permanece el último modelo llenado.

De 4 registros a almacenar, solo permanece 1.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacer la asignación masiva en un modelo, necesitas indicarle a dicho modelo que campos pueden ser "fillables" o no.

Por ejemplo

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tag extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'slug', 'color'];
    
    protected $guarded = ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
}
```

Debes usar uno de los dos métodos. Con **$guarded** especificamos solo los campos que **NO** serán llenos por asignación masiva, y con **$fillable** tenemos que indicar los campos que **SI** serán llenos por asignación masiva. Ya dependerá de ti que es lo que te convenga mas usar.

Lo que yo hago es, si en mi modelo, existen mas campos que **SI** serán fillables, entonces uso **$guarded**, eso lo que me hace es escribir menos código y dejar todo mas comprensible.

La [documentación de Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#mass-assignment) también nos dice que es mejor usar el método `create` en lugar del método `save`. Puedes también aprender mas de la Asignación Masiva con [este ejemplo](https://www.cursosdesarrolloweb.es/blog/asignacion-masiva-como-protegerse-en-laravel) o [este video](https://aprendible.com/series/laravel-desde-cero/lecciones/asignacion-masiva).

---

No olvides marcar la respuesta como **Aceptada** si resuelve tu problema/duda. :-)

Comment: Ya pude solucionar este problema, al igual que como comentas, yo estaba usando la función fill del modelo, y esto retiene la información en cache, pero si uso el metodo create directamente, puedo enviar el arreglo, y Laravel se encargaría de hacer el fill.